# How to get Jenkins to not include SVN file list in console output

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins to run PHPunit and prep pre-prod server from SVN for a PHP project.  My PHP project has over 5400 files included.  When I want to review the console output of the jenkins job, I have to scroll through the whole file list each time.  Is there a way I can get the jenkins svn check out to not list every file, just give me a file count in the console output?